# I cannot support these extra expenses

Tags: collocations

Do you think "support" is weird here?

I would write: I cannot bear/cover/meet/afford these extra expenses.

bear/cover/meet/afford expenses are collocations, while support expenses is not a collocation. Right?

Comment: Source please, Joy.  Please tell us exactly where you read this.  Why do you think the meaning is  "afford".  The meaning of "support" is different.  So I'd like to see the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not weird, but it has a slightly different meaning. The other verbs are more of an "order," while "support" is more of a "suggestion."

The other verbs you posted suggest that the speaker is explicitly denying a request to incur the expenses (probably because the speaker is the one who will be paying the expenses).

If you change it to "support," it sounds more like the speaker is expressing that the expenses are a bad idea (which probably means that the speaker is a third party who will not be paying the expenses but is concerned about incurring them).

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot support these extra expenses.

Could mean "I am not willing to vote for them" or MI am not willing to argue for them"  but it could also mean "I cannot afford them".

In the [definition of "Support" from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/support) sense 2 a (2) is "to uphold or defend as valid or right :  advocate" and sense 2 a (3) is "to argue or vote for // *supported the motion to lower taxes*"

But sense 3 a is: "to pay the costs of : maintain //  *support a family*"

Sense 3 a, used in this way, is perhaps a bit old-fashioned, but it is perfectly valid.